# ColumnSeries is not displayed at center position when LineSeries is added on Column Chart

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have mx:ColumnChart with multiple mx:ColumnSeries and multiple mx:LineSeries, the problem is that when ever i added LineSeries in Column Chart the column Series become smaller (tiny) and and also change position to left.

Comment: Is this in Flex 3 or Flex 4?  It doesn't make any sense to tag it with both.

Comment: Also see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-32348

Comment: Sorry to mention @Brian. Flex 3